# FFmpeg with x264 NEON support

Tags: video, pi-2, software-compilation

I was wondering if there any FFmpeg binaries that support NEON on the Raspberry Pi 2? Specifically x264 with NEON support compiled into the FFmpeg binary, x264 supports NEON on Android so it should definitely support it on the Pi2 as well.

There is a FFmpeg [compilation guide for the Pi1](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/RaspberryPi) but not for the Pi2 and I'm not sure if setting the gcc flags `-funsafe-math-optimizations` and `-mfpu=neon-vfpv4` will do the trick. I guess I would need to specifically enable it in some config.

It was said that NEON would increase video encoding performance by ~30x in some cases like x264 encoding. So an FFmpeg NEON binary would be really interesting to have.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this when you compile:

```
-mcpu=cortex-a8 -mfpu=neon
```

What CPU capabilities does x.264 report at runtime? I get this on my old model B:

```
x264 [info]: using cpu capabilities: none!
```

You should be seeing NEON on the PI 2.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use "cortex-a8"? The Pi2 ARM is a Cortex A7.